# gradle project reimport failed (zip END header)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Все работало отлично. В один из запусков что-то сломалось. Никак не могу понять в чем проблема. Когда добавляю новую зависимость выдает ошибку `gradle project reimport failed`. Захожу в View -> Tool -> Gradle и там во вкладке делаю reimportant all gradle proj, но выдает в консоль следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте удалить папку `~/<username>/.gradle/wrapper/dists/<gradle-name>` и перестроить проект

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалил папки `.idea` and `.gradle` из корневой папки проекта и все. Затем при запуске проекта `Idea` сама все подтянула.